# How can I change the email address used to log in to Windows 8?

Tags: login, username

I had to delete my hard drive after I encountered serious errors on my laptop. When logging in by setting up my account profile I made a mistake on my email address. When I tried to change this I was not allowed to make my Hotmail account as the primary account. I have just downloaded all my info and files again. Can you please help me to rectify this?

Comment: The first step is to unlink your local account, then you will be allowed to link the your local account, to the correct Microsoft Account

Answer (score 0):

Hover in the bottom right corner of the screen:

In the right toolbar > Settings > Change PC Settings > Your Account > Other Accounts

Here you can add your targeted account. Once you've done that go to Your Account and click Disconnect against the one you wish to remove.